# Cannot connect HDMI second monitor on Xubuntu on a Dell Precision 7730

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, dell, hdmi, radeon

I have a new Dell Precision 7730 laptop and I have installed Xubuntu on it, everything works except the fact that I can't connect my second external monitor to it with an HDMI cable (which works just fine on Windows).

The computer has a hybrid graphics card system. Running *lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'* gives:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3e94]
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin [Radeon Pro WX 4130/4150] [1002:67e8]
```

And according to *xrandr*:

```
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I have installed the amdgpu-pro drivers (following the tutorial on ATI's website) and I still can't fix it. The only weird thing is that, when I shut the computer down, the second monitor briefly turns on and shows the Xubuntu splash image before shutting down.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?